# Rename [libre-office] to [libreoffice]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org) is one word, however the tag [libre-office](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libre-office) is hyphenated.
Can the tag be renamed [libreoffice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) to reflect the correct word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. Thanks for pointing this out.